# How do I synthesize 3-hydroxydihydrofuran-2-one from formaldehyde?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I want to synthesize 3-hydroxydihydrofuran-2-one from formaldehyde but I do not know of a method. I tried a Mannich reaction and lactonization after dehydration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from pyruvic acid which is readily available and not very expensive: react pyruvic acid (only one enolizable side) with a Mannich base, then react the resulting amide with $\ce{MeI}$ and base to obtain the exo-methylene product. Brominate the exo-methylene. Now cyclization will prefer the five-membered ring over the strained four-membered ring. Reduce the ketone with a reletively mild reducing agent like $\ce{NaBH4}$ and then eliminate $\ce{HBr}$ in a E1cB type reaction, yielding 3-hydroxydihydrofuran-2-one.

This synthesis involves a Mannich reaction as you asked, but it can be done much simpler without it I think.

**Note:** I'm not an expert, just an enthusiastic amateur. Before trying anything in the lab  make sure your synthesis is checked by a supervisor.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Your explanation is very clear.
Fortunately, I don't make anything in laboratory, just I write this synthesis in my homework, but thanks for the prompt.

Comment: Jori, can you show me the other method without the Mannich reaction?
Thanks a lot for the help